# I have a JSON Service that returns results with "\n" when InputStreamReader reads the result "\" is gone

Tags: json, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textarea

I have a JSON Service that returns results with "\n" when `InputStreamReader` reads the result the "\" is gone and leaving the "n" in the String.

I'm having trouble converting the "\n" to next line to be displayed in a TextArea.

For example:

```
Service Result: Hello\nWorld
PassThrough InputStreamReader: HellonWorld
TextArea Output: HellonWorld
```

I need it to be:

```
Service Result: Hello\nWorld
PassThrough InputStreamReader: Hello
World
TextArea Output: Hello
World
```

Please help me on how to result this problem.

I'm using LWUIT and is developing for a J2ME device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to do this but here it is:

Add the following lines to the JSONParser.java

```
else if (c == 'n') {
    c = '\n';
}
```

below

```
c = (char) i.read();
if (c == 'u') {
    String unicode = "" + ((char) i.read()) + ((char) i.read()) + ((char) i.read()) + ((char) i.read());
    try {
        c = (char) Integer.parseInt(unicode, 16);
    } catch (NumberFormatException err) {
        // problem in parsing the u notation!
        err.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error in parsing \\u" + unicode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the exact JSON string returned. If the data is within double quotes `"` then it shouldn't be modified at all with the exception of decoding the `\u` notations.

Comment: Solved the problem already. Yeah, that should be the case, but from the service I'm accessing, I need to handle it. Thank you very much anyways!
it's something like this anyways:
"description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n consectetur adipiscing elit."